# Слово "сексот": когда и почему перестало употребляться?

Tags: история

В нашем детстве (50-60  годы прошлого века) не было более унизительного, презрительного прозвища, чем "сексот". Недавно я обнаружил, что не только дети и молодые люди сегодня не употребляют и не понимают этого слова, но и люди пятидесятилетнего возраста. Какова же история этого существительного? И почему оно вышло из активного употребления?

Comment: В нашем детстве (80-90 годы в городе "среди берёзок средней полосы") его, скорее всего, почти никто и не знал.

Comment: Эпоха лагерей и массовых репрессий в это время уже отошла в прошлое. Но, конечно, география тоже что-то значила. Я жил в детстве на Дальнем Востоке и в Казахстане, т.е. местах ссылок и лагерей.

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, слово *не прижилось* в языке по причине своего происхождения из профессионального жаргона и умерло задолго до стихания самого явления (в 70-е оно ещё процветало - вместе с коммунальными квартирами и с привлечением к информаторству студентов), будучи заменённым на более употребительное и явно презрительное "стукач". Возможно даже, это слово звучало излишне комплиментарно и романтично*. А со временем оно могло и просто забыться за ненадобностью, как аббревиатуры "нацмен" или "нэпман". Иначе происходили изменения с неформальным обозначением милиционеров, которых в 70-е широко именовали "легавыми", что было явно обидно для сотрудников милиции (даже в одном фильме с досадой об этом говорилось) - со временем (возможно, к этому прикладывались усилия в СМИ), милиционеров (как со стороны, так и в порядке неформального самоназвания) стали называть забытым словом "мент", которое держится и сейчас.

**P.S.** *Такое предположение подтверждается и тем, что в фильме "Бриллиантовая рука" (1968) есть реплика Семён-Семёныча, в которой он обращается к Лёлику (до отклеивания у него уса) "товарищ сексот) - явно не в значении "стукача", а в значении вполне уважаемого агента спецслужбы на задании.

Comment: *Без сексотов меморандум составить было бы просто невозможно (сексот ― секретный сотрудник ― так советские люди называли ненавидимое ими племя осведомителей ГПУ, НКВД, МГБ и т. д.); [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 2 (1978)].*  Думаю, реплика Семён-Семёныча, делавшего и произносившего многое некстати, должна была вызывать смех.

Comment: Вот они ― фальшивые инженерские и литературные экспертизы, речи, разоблачающие врагов народа, вот они ― задушевные разговоры и дружеские признания, переложенные в донесения и рапорты сексотов-стукачей, информаторов. [Василий Гроссман. Все течет (1955-1963) // «Октябрь», 1989]

Comment: Все это - примеры из 60-70-х годов. И употребляют это слово люди, родившиеся в первые десятилетия ХХ века. В 80-е годы уже точно дети его не употребляли. 70-е - под вопросом. Нужны информаторы.